# which data type to select in MySql

Tags: sql, mysql, sqldatatypes

I have a Csv file and a data column which has 2 data type integer and text both in same column.

In MySQL what data type can i choose?

I tried to upload csv in MySql, but i get import error as column as 2 datatypes, but both 2 data type are important to me.

what should i do?

Comment: If it's a mix of integer and text in the same column, your only choice is VARCHAR. A numeric column will not allow text content. Note that you're going to have problems with queries, because the numeric data in that column will be treated as strings, not numbers. For instance, they will not sort properly because they're not numbers.

Comment: "...but both 2 data type are important to me..." -- then separate them in two distinct columns. Then, you can use them as integers or text and apply any logic you want. A relational database is not an Excel sheet and has strict requirements in terms of data types.

Comment: Maybe it would help to explain in detail what values you can have in this column and what to do with it. What is the purpose of the column?

Comment: Provide a sample of CSV lines with these 2 datatypes and desired final data state.

Comment: Please show an example.  And explain whether the two parts need to be used for computation, filtering, etc.